# custom border color in Calendar in eCharts

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

Here is my Echart Heatmap Calendar's code:

```
option = {
    visualMap: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10000,
        type: 'piecewise',
        orient: 'horizontal',
        left: 'center',
        top: 65,

    },
    calendar: {
        top: 120,
        left: 30,
        right: 30,
        cellSize: ['auto', 13],
        range: '2016',
        itemStyle: {
            borderWidth: 0.5
        },
        yearLabel: {show: false}
    },
    series: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        coordinateSystem: 'calendar',
        data: getVirtulData(2016)
    }
};
```

[image]

So want to change the color of months border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `splitLine` object in `calendar`.

```
calendar: {
    top: 120,
    left: 30,
    right: 30,
    cellSize: ['auto', 13],
    range: '2016',
    splitLine:{
      lineStyle:{
          color:'red' // This will change the border color
      }  
    },
    itemStyle: {
        borderWidth: 0.5,
    },
    yearLabel: {show: false}
},
```